# How to reset/clear the active record after a TDataSet.Locate successfull

Tags: delphi, dataset

I am trying to modify a legacy Delphi 2007 application.

Under certain conditions, I want make sure no record been selected for a table by supply invalid keys before calling the TDataSet.Locate function. The general process is:

1. User select an item (Key No. 1 for example) in a list from Grid
2. User do something in other screens (X, Y, Z for example) which all using Key No. 1 to retrieve data in other tables
3. But on one screen (say it to be screen X), I want the grid forget the
   selected item, but should still had the list and data, just nothing been selected again. and all other screen should not load any data unless the user starting from step 1 again to select an item from the list again.

The current application will always have a item selected without user specifically select anything, which will be the first record in the list, and it  will almost certainly never be the right one. It can be slightly improved by make sure the most recently change record been selected by default, which will be right sometimes but not most of the times. I think a better approach would be 
ask the user always to select an item in the first screen in the list, and again after they finished screen Z.

So the first thing I tried is to do a locate for invalid index. But of course it doesn't working as Locate will not change the last active record if new Locate failed (find no record). Consequently, there will always an activated record.

My question is, is there any way I can reset/clear out the activate record after there been successful Locate?

Comment: Activate a filter condition that always returns false. On the other hand I cannot see any sense in doing such thing. Can you elaborate on your intentions?

Comment: The whole design of TDataSet is based on the idea that if a dataset is not empty, the dataset's cursor is positioned on exactly one record; that is the active record and you cannot avoid this behaviour.  I'm surprised you are worried about this.  Which TDataSet descendant are you actually using?

Comment: Looks like an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: That's the point of checking the `Boolean` result. If `Locate` returns `False`, you should not be trying to process the active row ***at all***.

Comment: Sorry guys, I know it is hard trying to help if I am asking how to do xyz but my intention is not clear. I think I probably will try the filter condition for now.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe, can you put an example of how to use filter. I've put code to set filter to a false condition, and set Filtered to True when the locate found nothing and return False (I assume that's because I've already set the key to non-existing records), But the the dataset is not empty and the number of records counting by traverse didn't seems change after I set the filter?

Comment: I guess it is not possible to achieve this. If the data shall be visible in the grid then there always is a selected record. You cannot avoid that.